# What is the location of Defrag.exe on the Windows 7 DVD?

Tags: windows, defragment

I can't find **defrag.exe** on the Windows 7 DVD in its default location, which is supposedly here: `C:\Windows\System32`

Knowing that you can defragment using the GUI tools from the DVD (which I don't want), defrag.exe must exist somewhere on the DVD. But where?

Edit: It seems that the file is missing even if I search for it with `X: dir -s defrag.exe`

That means Windows' defragmenter must be in another form/file, does it ?

Comment: I am not so sure that the defragmentation tool is available from the installation DVD. But if it is, you should be able to pinpoint its location with the `dir` command by running it from the installation system root, with the `s` switch.

Comment: What do you need defrag.exe for anyway? Some kind of automation? There might be other ways to achieve your goal without it. There are also third-party tools that are bootable and do defragmentation on NTFS and FAT filesystems.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the GUI tools you refer to? Are you referring to System Recovery Options? I don't think you have the defragmentation tool there.

Comment: I need it since I can't boot from USB (Bios locked), and that I don't have any DVD to burn now. The purpose of defragmenting is to speed up boot times, which is plain slow due to the huge amount of starting programs.

Comment: Always be prepared and have a Linux Live disc at hand with the tools you like or need the most. Today that's usually a fully functional "live" Linux distribution. The purpose-built ones like System Rescue CD tend to have outdated software that does not support modern hardware. This appears to be a trend right now. We are also moving away from Live CD to Live DVD and Live USB. That's why special tools are neede to properly build a worling Live USB from a Live CD ISO image. Either way... be prepared. You might also be interested in building your very own Windows PE image for Windows needs.

Comment: How long does it take to boot? To speed up boot times it's best if you can change the HDD for an SSD drie. The next best thing is to have Windows reinstalled. On Windows 8 you can do a refresh, but not on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm always prepared but with a LiveUSB Linux, but I can't use anything else than a Live CD since my BIOS is locked. And since it's a company laptop, I can't change any hardware inside. By the way, it takes like 5 minutes to be stabilized enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows uses a large .WIM file since Vista on the DVD/ISO. Here you can find defrag.exe under:

```
DRIVELETTER:\sources\install.wim\1\Windows\System32\
```

You can open the [Install.wim with 7-zip](http://blog.nirsoft.net/2009/09/17/how-to-extract-missing-system-files-from-the-dvd-of-windows-7vista/) to extract a file.

If you get file corruptions, run [sfc /Scannow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/928228/en-us) first.

Comment: The question is not solvable, but this is the closest answer I can get.

Answer (score 1):

You could try searching for it using the **dir** command.

1. Boot from the Windows 7 DVD.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.
3. Make sure you are at `X:\`.
4. If you are not at `X:\`, then type `cd /` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. Type in `dir defrag.exe /s` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If it's on the DVD it should find it and show you the path.

Comment: Didn't knew that dir had a "find" option, thanks. But unfortunately, it says File Not Found, which is really weird. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Well... it sort of does. It's not like `find -name` on Linux though. It's more like `ls` but with a twist. It essentially lists files in the current directory, but with the `s` switch it does this recursively for all sub directories.

Comment: I just ran the command on an installed instance of Windows 8.1 and I found it in `C:\Windows\System32` and another version of it in a sub directory of `C:\Windows\WinSxS\`. So the command is working. If you read "File Not Found" then it means what it says, I'm sure of it. Are you sure you are at the filesystem root when you issue the command?

Comment: @X.LINK Try to do `cd /` first and then the command. I believe you land in `X:\Sources` by default.

Comment: Yep, I was back to X:'s root before doing dir -s

Comment: @X.LINK If you are not able to locate the file, then you simply don't have it. And if you don't have it, but you want it, then you might need to create your own Windows 7 installation DVD, with the defrag.exe included, using Windows PE and AIK.

Comment: Files on the installation DVD are likely to be compressed (with a different suffix) or within ".cab" files.  You will only find ".exe" files on the installation DVD which are needed in the actual install procedure.

Comment: Just to be clear... are you saying that even if there was a file on the DVD, named defrag.exe, it would be a compressed file? So it would not run? I am trying to understand your remark about suffix. A Cab file is the most probable container for it, and once you obtain the exe from it, it would be executable, not compressed. It would be deceiving to use exe suffix for an executable. The problem lies in finding the right Cab file and extracting it.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 7 DVD is compressed into CAB files I don't know which one but you will have open one the CAB files to find it, Finding it and trying to open it probably won't work anyway

Comment: Right... let's reverse-engineer Windows so we can run defrag.exe. A Cab file is a library of compressed files. They form a set of files that are extracted automatically, typically during installation of a Microsoft software. A file in a Cab can span across multiple other Cab files.

Comment: You don't happen to know what Cab file defrag.exe is stored in? Don't bother looking for it, it still won't work because you don't have write access to unpack to DVD. You could target a mounted HDD, but you will still need a tool to unpack Cab. Most likely, you will have to store it on and run it from the HDD. To get it onto the HDD you will have to obtain the tool... from the web probably... and save it on the HDD. To do that, you will need to mount the HDD on a fully worling system with net access. Hamster in a wheel... just forget it.